# Выдает ошибку 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFDFDFDFD. В функции умножения матрицы

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

class matrix
{
private:
    int column;
    int row;
    int **mass2;
    int size;
public:
    matrix() {
        column = 0; // конструктор по умолчанию
        row = 0;
        mass2 = 0;
        size = 0;
    }


    matrix(int **array, int n, int k) //конструктор иницилизации
    {
        size = n;
        mass2 = new int*[size];


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            mass2[i] = new int[k];
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                mass2[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }

    }


matrix multiple(const matrix &A, const matrix &B, int n, int k)
    {
        matrix buf;
        buf.mass2 = new int*[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            buf.mass2[i] = new int[k];


            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

                for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)

                {
                    buf.mass2[i][j] = 0;

                    for (int l = 0; l <= k + 1; l++)

                        buf.mass2[i][j] = (A.mass2[i][l] * B.mass2[l][j]) + 

                        buf.mass2[i][j];
                }
            }

        return buf;
    }


void print(int n, int k) 

    {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                cout << setw(5) << mass2[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;

    }
};




int main()
    {

        int n, n1, p, k,kof;

        //matrix    chislo;
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
        cout << "Введите для матрицы  кол-во рядов" << endl;
        cin >> n;
        cout << "Введите для матрицы  кол-во столбцов" << endl;
        cin >> k;

        cout << "Введите коеффициент" << endl;
        cin >> kof;

        cout << "Введите елементы матрицы" << endl;
        int **mass1 = new int*[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            mass1[i] = new int[k];
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                cin >> mass1[i][j];
            }

        }

    matrix array1(mass1, n, k);
    matrix array2(mass1, n, k);
    array1.print(n,k);
    array2.print(n, k);

        matrix  array4_mult;
        array4_mult.multiple(array1,array2, n, k);
        cout << "Умножение двух матриц = " << endl;
        array4_mult.print(k,n);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Забавно, что вы не храните размеры матриц в самих матрицах... Нет, если они могут быть только квадратными, то все в порядке, но тогда - почему два параметра размеров? И как вы собираетесь умножать матрицы, скажем, размером 3x2 обе? :)
Это не единственная проблема, код ниже всякой критики. Например, вот вы матрицы умножаете:

```
matrix  array4_mult;
array4_mult.multiple(array1,array2, n, k);
cout << "Умножение двух матриц = " << endl;
array4_mult.print(k,n);
```

Сами сообразите, почему ничего не будет выведено? Вы же - в вашем варианте умножения - просто выбрасываете его результат... И это далеко не единственная ошибка.

Ну, а с вашими проблемами - тут все не просто просто, а очень просто:

```
buf.mass2[i] = new int[k];
```

т.е. максимальный второй индекс - `k-1`. А тут

```
for (int l = 0; l <= k + 1; l++)
    buf.mass2[i][j] = (A.mass2[i][l] * B.mass2[l][j]) + 
                       buf.mass2[i][j];
```

вы обращаетесь даже не по индексу `k`, а `k+1`. За пределы выделенной памяти.

**Update** Раз вы считаете, что дело в одном знаке...

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)   // Итак, переменная i
{
    buf.mass2[i] = new int[k];  // Пусть она равна 0, память выделена только для mass2[0]
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // Опять i, скрывающая предыдущую!
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            buf.mass2[i][j] = 0;   // И куда будет обращение, когда НОВОЕ i будет больше 0?
```

Вам нужно переписывать код, а не лечить симптомы...

Comment: Исправил на k-1 в строчке for (int l = 0; l <= k + 1; l++), но все равно выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: Теперь смотрите - вы обращаетесь к `buf.mass2[i]` еще даже не выделив для него память. Кроме того, у вас два вложенных цикла с одной индексной переменной. Я думал, что ясно дал понять, что полумеры ваш код не спасут, и простое изменение одного знака на другой ничего не даст. Вам нужно переписывать заново, причем с пониманием того, что вы делаете. Эти ошибки доступа к памяти - вершина айсберга...

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: это не айсберг, это гора вермишели

Answer (score 2):

Не буду перечислять все те же проблемы что упомянул Harry, они являются частностями, результатом неверного построения класса.

Реализация класса  , как она существует сейчас, идет в разрез со здравым смыслом.  Есть правило, гласящее, что объект, использующий ресурс, этот ресурс и размещает. А у вас что? Операция умножения (кстати, а почему не оператор?) размещает память для результата. Сделайте это в конструкторе, который будет принимать размерность матрицы. Более умная реализация будет размещать память отложенно, когда матрице или элементу матрицы будет дано хоть одно значение.

Вам так же нужен конструктор глубокого копирования (который создаст область памяти под значения). Как вообще вы собираетесь передавать данные? 
В том виде как он существует сейчас, копия объекта матрицы, возвращенная из функции , будет содержать копию значения поля-указателя? И кто владелец этого объекта в памяти? И если матрица перестает существовать, что происходит с этим массивом?

Умножение матриц происходит  по принципу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть каждый элемент результата  - это скалярное произведение строки на столбец, а следовательно надо проверять размерность матриц: количество столбцов А д.б. равно количеству строк В, количество строк А д.б. равно количеству столбцов В.

Способ реализации матрицы через псевдо-двумерный разорванный массив не очень хорош. В реальности у вас нет двумерного массива, есть массив указателей на массивы, раскиданные по памяти как ядру ОС в голову пришло. В ряде случаев, когда вам нужна будет непрерывная матрица для передачи куда-то (OpenCL, OpenGL, фортрановский код), такая матрица неприменима, да и не оптимальна сама по себе. Быстрее будет работать (и надежнее) с одномерным массивом, для которого вы вычислите индекс исходя из номера столбца и строки (в таком случае можно даже обойтись одним циклом вместо двух вложенных).
И наконец прежде чем определять, что строка массива эквивалентна строке матрице, следует выяснить, для какой задачи вы собираетесь использовать матрицы. Например, для поиска собственных значений или для работы с преобразованием координат в 3х мерном (или более?) пространстве, лучше пользоваться транспонированным представлением. В этих случаях вообще используются квадратные матрицы, и есть смысл создать оптимизированный класс, работающий только с квадратными (а возможно еще и класс разреженной матрицы). Для 3д-графики обычно используют специализированную матрицу 4х4. Если же задача абстрактна, то все в порядке.

Comment: плюсик поставили, а очепятку не заметили )